# Possible to have PHP MYSQL query ignore empty variable in WHERE clause?

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

Not sure how I can do this.  Basically I have variables that are populated with a combobox and then passed on to form the filters for a MQSQL query via the where clause.  What I need to do is allow the combo box to be left empty by the user and then have that variable ignored in the where clause.  Is this possible?

i.e., from this code.  Assume that the combobox that populates $value1 is left empty, is there any way to have this ignored and only the 2nd filter applied.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM moth_sightings WHERE user_id = '$username' AND location = '$value1' AND english_name = $value2 ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$r = mysql_numrows($result);
```

Thanks for any help.
C

Comment: check if `$value1` is empty and do not append `AND location = '$value1'` to query. BTW don't use `mysql_*` since it deprecated

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use

```
$where = "WHERE user_id = '$username'";

if(!empty($value1)){
$where .= "and location = '$value1'";
}

if(!empty($value2 )){
$where .= "and english_name= '$value2 '";
}


$query = "SELECT * FROM moth_sightings $where";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$r = mysql_numrows($result);
```

Comment: apologies.  Did not click that on purpose. It won't let me vote up since I am a new user, but this was extremely helpful.  Again I apologize for the accidental vote down.

Comment: I don't know who did it, but voted up again, also change the WHERE in the IF's into AND, and leave space after '$value1', else it won't work ;)

Answer (score 6):

Several other answers mention the risk of SQL injection, and a couple explicitly mention using prepared statements, but none of them explicitly show how you might do that, which might be a big ask for a beginner.

My current preferred method of solving this problem uses a MySQL "IF" statement to check whether the parameter in question is null/empty/0 (depending on type). If it is empty, then it compares the field value against itself ( `WHERE field1=field1` always returns `true`). If the parameter is not empty/null/zero, the field value is compared against the parameter.

So here's an example using MySQLi prepared statements (assuming $mysqli is an already-instantiated mysqli object):

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM moth_sightings 
        WHERE user_id = ? 
            AND location = IF(? = '', location, ?)
            AND english_name = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $value1, $value1, $value2);
$stmt->execute();
```

(I'm assuming that `$value2` is a string based on the field name, despite the lack of quotes in OP's example SQL.)

There is no way in MySQLi to bind the same parameter to multiple placeholders within the statement, so we have to explicitly bind `$value1` twice. The advantage that MySQLi has in this case is the explicit typing of the parameter - if we pass in `$value1` as a string, we know that we need to compare it against the empty string `''`. If `$value1` were an integer value, we could explicitly declare that like so:

```
$stmt->bind_param('siis', $username, $value1, $value1, $value2);
```

and compare it against `0` instead.

Here is a PDO example using named parameters, because I think they result in much more readable code with less counting:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM moth_sightings 
    WHERE user_id = :user_id 
        AND location = IF(:location_id = '', location, :location_id)
        AND english_name = :name";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$params = [
    ':user_id' => $username,
    ':location_id' => $value1,
    ':name' => $value2
];
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Note that with PDO named parameters, we can refer to `:location_id` multiple times in the query while only having to bind it once.

Answer (score 0):

Sure,

```
$sql = "";
if(!empty($value1))
  $sql = "AND location = '{$value1}' ";
if(!empty($value2))
  $sql .= "AND english_name = '{$value2}'";

$query = "SELECT * FROM moth_sightings WHERE user_id = '$username' {$sql} ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$r = mysql_numrows($result);
```

Be aware of sql injection and deprecation of mysql_*, use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: you have a typo in the last instance of variable `$sql`. You wrote `$sq`. I tried editing but couldn't (6 letter min.)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( isset($value1) )
 $query = "SELECT * FROM moth_sightings WHERE user_id = '$username' AND location = '$value1' AND english_name = $value2 ";
else
 $query = "SELECT * FROM moth_sightings WHERE user_id = '$username' AND english_name = $value2 ";
```

But, you can also make a function to return the query based on the inputs you have. 
And also don't forget to escape your `$values` before generating the query.

Answer (score 0):

1.) don't use the simply mysql php extension, use either the advanced mysqli extension or the much safer PDO / MDB2 wrappers.

2.) don't specify the full statement like that (apart from that you dont even encode and escape the values given...). Instead use something like this:

```
sprintf("SELECT * FROM moth_sightings WHERE 1=1 AND %s", ...);
```

Then fill that raw query using an array holding all values you actually get from your form:

```
$clause=array(
  'user_id="'.$username.'"',
  'location="'.$value1.'"',
  'english_name="'.$value2.'"'
);
```

You can manipulate this array in any way, for example testing for empty values or whatever. Now just implode the array to complete the raw question from above:

```
sprintf("SELECT * FROM moth_sightings WHERE 1=1 AND %s", 
        implode(' AND ', $clause) );
```

Big advantage: even if the clause array is completely empty the query syntax is valid.

Answer (score 0):

First, please read about [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).
Second, $r = mysql_numrows($result) should be $r = mysql_num_rows($result);

You can use IF in MySQL, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM moth_sightings WHERE user_id = '$username' AND IF('$value1'!='',location = '$value1',1) AND IF('$value2'!='',english_name = '$value2',1); -- BUT PLEASE READ ABOUT SQL Injections. Your code is not safe.
```

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of SQL injections.  This is just to help me learn before I get to that.

Comment: okay. hope the IFs in MySQL will help you with your concern. The syntax for if is IF (condition,[if true],[if false]). In [if false], I placed '1' to just return true so it would not affect the other conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of two other ways to solve this:

```
SELECT * FROM moth_sightings
WHERE
      user_id = '$username'
      AND location = '%$value1%'

      AND english_name = $value2 ";
```

This will return results only for this `user_id`, where the location field contains `$value1`. **If $value1 is empty**, this will still return all rows for this `user_id`, blank or not.

---

**OR**

```
SELECT * FROM moth_sightings
WHERE
      user_id = '$username'
      AND (location = '$value1' OR location IS NULL OR location = '')
      AND english_name = $value2 ";
```

This will give you all rows for this `user_id` that have `$value1` for location or have blank values.